# Multiple Fragments and Screen Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-webview, screen-orientation

I'm a newbie in android programming. I'm trying to develop a simple browser using webview and fragments. This is what I have done:

- Created one empty activity(`MainActivity`)
- Created two fragments(`HomeFragment` and `WebFragment`)
- Placed one edittext and a button on top of `activity_main.xml`
- Below that a fragment is added
- `HomeFragment` is loaded there by default
- A method `changeFragment()` is created and called to load `WebFragment` when a button click or action down occurred.
- A URL is read from edittext and passed to `WebFragment` through bundle
- A webview is created on `WebFragment` and the URL is loaded.

And here comes the problem: When orientation is changed the fragment with webview will cause force close. There is no such problems with the first fragment. To solve this I added this to manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

and these lines to MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}
```

And here comes the next problem: `HomeFragment` have a portrait layout and a landscape layout. But on orientation change the view won't change.
Is there any way so that I can display the two variants of `HomeFragment` on curresponding orientation change and to keep the present view on `WebFragment`?